# Ursprung der Verbnachstellung im Nebensatz

Tags: history

Stimmt es, dass die Nachstellung des Hauptverbs im Nebensatz, so wie etwa in diesem Nebensatz hier, auf das Bemühen mittelalterlicher Mönche zurückgeht die lateinische Satzstellung auf das deutsche zu übertragen?

Die Nachstellung des Verbs ist global gesehen ja sogar eher die Norm als die Ausnahme: in den meisten Sprachen der Welt wird das Verb nachgestellt. Neben dem Latein findet sich dies auch in anderen indogermanischen Sprachen wie etwa Persisch oder Hindi, oder auch in den Turksprachen oder im Japanischen.

Die weiträumige Verbnachstellung ist ja eher die Ausnahme in den Sprachen Westeuropas. Hat das Deutsche diese singulär erworben unter seinen Nachbarn? Wenn ja, geht dies auf lateinsprachige Mönche zurück? Oder umgekehrt, ist die Verbzweitstellung im Hauptsatz eine jüngere Innovation?

Comment: Ich habe 'mal gelernt, dass die Satzstellung im Lateinischen völlgi frei ist?

Comment: Dass mittelalterliche Mönche den Sprachgebrauch der Millionen von nicht-mönchischen Sprechern derart nachhaltig beeinflusst haben, scheint mir unwahrscheinlich. Die allermeisten von ihnen werden in ihrem Leben keinen Mönch sprechen hören und kein mönch-geschriebenes Buch gelesen haben.

Comment: @IQV: Theoretisch ist die lateinische Satzstellung sehr frei. Praktisch gehen die Verben aber eher ans Satzende.

Answer (score 3):

Nach etwas Nachforschung kann ich nun meine eigene Frage beantworten. Dass die Verbnachstellung im Nebensatz von Mönchen aus dem Latein ins Deutsche übernommen wurde ist tatsächlich ein schlechter Mythos (den ich vielleicht aus einem schlechten Schulbuch übernommen habe).

Tatsächlich ist die Verbnachstellung die ursprüngliche Satzordnung der germanischen Sprachen. In der protogermanischen Ursprache stand das Verb stets am Ende. Aus der englischsprachigen Wikipedia [(Link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Germanic_grammar#Syntax):

> The general word order was subject–object–verb: objects preceded their
>   verbs [...]

Die Zweitstellung des Verbs im Hauptsatz ist hingegen eine spätere Innovation:

> At some point in the history of the language, it became more frequent
>   to place finite verbs second in the sentence, perhaps beginning with
>   auxiliary verbs. That survives most clearly in Dutch and German, where
>   the auxiliary verb is placed second, but the remaining verbs are still
>   placed at the end. However, most modern Germanic languages, including
>   Dutch and German, have a more restrictive word order known as V2 word
>   order, in which the finite verb, whether it is an auxiliary or not, is
>   always placed second in main clauses (however not in Dutch and German
>   subordinate clauses). It also remained optional for a long time, with
>   verbs still occasionally appearing in other positions for poetic
>   reasons in Middle Dutch.

Im Altenglischen war die Worstellung sogar in den Grundzügen immer noch wie im heutigen Hochdeutsch [(Link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_grammar#Syntax).

> Main clauses in Old English tend to have a verb-second (V2) order,
>   where the verb is the second constituent in a sentence, regardless of
>   what comes first. [...] If the subject appears first, there is an SVO
>   order, but it can also yield orders such as OVS and others. In
>   questions VSO was common, see below.
>
> In subordinate clauses, however, the word order is completely
>   different, with verb-final constructions the norm, again as in German.
>   Furthermore, in poetry, all the rules were frequently broken.

Wieder was gelernt.

Answer (score 0):

Als Ergänzung zu deiner eigenen sehr guten Antwort:

Die ursprüngliche Reihenfolge dürfte SOV gewesen sein (bei mehreren Objekten auch OSOV). Diese Reihenfolge gilt heute nich n Relativsätzen:

> Ich esse Äpfel, weil **ich Äpfel mag.**
>
> Ich bin froh, weil **Gabi mir die Welt zeigte.** (1)
>   Ich bin froh, weil **mir Gabi die Welt zeigte.** (2)

Wenn man in diesen Sätzen das Verb an die Position 1 stellt (und den Rest unverändert lässt) entsteht VSO, und das ist die Reihenfolge, die in geschlossenen Fragen verwendet wird. (Eine geschlossene Frage erwartet *ja* oder *nein* als Antwort):

> Mag ich Äpfel?
>
> Zeigte Gabi mir die Welt? (1)
>   Zeigte mir Gabi die Welt? (2)

Wenn man dann noch ein anders Satzglied (egal welches) vor das Verb stellt, kann alles mögliche entstehen, ander das Verb steht dann an Position 2, und das ist der typische Satzbau für deutsche Hauptsätze:

> Ich mag Äpfel.
>   Äpfel mag ich.
>
> Gabi zeigte mir die Welt. (aus 1 u. 2)
>   Mir zeigte Gabi die Welt. (aus 1 u. 2)
>   Die Welt zeigte Gabi mir. (aus 1)
>   Die Welt zeigte mir Gabi. (aus 2)

Ich bin mir aber nicht im Klaren darüber, ob diese These tatsächlich eine reale historische Entwicklung wiedergibt, oder ob das lediglich eine theoretische Erklärung für den modernen deutschen V2-Satzbau ist.